# Why is XPath count() not working for me in PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, count

I am trying to get the amount of all section heading elements (`H1`,`H2`,`H3`,`H4`,`H5`,`H6`) from a document using XPath, e.g.:

```
    $headerCount=$xpath->query("count(//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or self::h6])");
```

I tested above query on http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath with this example and got '6' as result:

```
<h2>Header 1</h2>
<h2>Header 2</h2>
<h3>Header 2.1</h3>
<h4>Header 2.1.1</h4>
<h2>Header 3</h2>
<h3>Header 3.1</h3>
```

But when I try to use $headerCount like this:

```
echo "count: ".$headerCount->textContent;
```

I get this error:

`Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$textContent`

`DOMNodeList` suggests that there is a list of nodes, but I thought it is just one numeric value, such as 6 for the amount of all headers.

Anybody who could shed some light on how I can just get the amount of all headings in a document?

Comment: Do note that according to [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) DOMXPath::query only returns DOMNodeList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is fine; it's your PHP that requires adjustment (as Alejandro [pointed out in a helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614195/xpath-get-count-of-all-section-heading-elements-in-a-document#comment105391985_59614195)).

Use [`DOMXPath::evaluate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) instead of [`DOMXPath::query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php):

```
$headerCount=$xpath->evaluate("count(//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or self::h6])");
```

Then `$headerCount` will be *just one numeric value, such as 6 for the amount of all headers,* as expected.